# PayPal Sandbox developer account ask me the enter Credit card information

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have paypal sandbox test account.  I am trying it with HTML form. It displays a 'Buy Now' button on HTML page and after clicking on it redirects to PayPal site. Where it ask to login to buy product but after that it is asking me the credit card information. I think as it is sand-box account it shouldn't ask me credit card as it is for testing purpose. I am right? please correct me and advice.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you set up your sandbox seller account you can also set up fake buyer accounts that you can use by logging in with or create fake credit cards with for testing. This lets you go through the whole process so you can test/develop your PDTsuccess and IPN success stuff if you want...

Here is [how to make this buyer account](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_testing_sandbox_get_started#personal)

Answer (score -1):

I have very little experience with Paypal, but I think that sandbox accounts should ask for credit card numbers.  How else can you test whether you are getting the correct responses in case of a valid payment/failed payment?